# Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported. while using opencv

Tags: python, linux, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread("lena.jpg", 0)

cv.imshow("image", img)
x = cv.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

cv.destroyAllWindows()
cv.imwrite("lena.copy.png", img)
```

After running that code on pycharm on Linux OS, the image shown but it is throwing an error
`Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I have the same problem.